# Назначение прав администратора в Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.6

делаю учебный проект корпоративного сайта на Laravel, учебные материалы созданы на версии 5.2. Я делаю на 5.7. 
Столкнулся с проблемой авторизации пользователей. 
В учебном видео автор реализует назначение прав администратору через шлюз Gate в AuthServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace Corp\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Corp\User;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    'Corp\Model' => 'Corp\Policies\ModelPolicy',
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

    $this->registerPolicies();


    Gate::define('VIEW_ADMIN', function($user) {


        return $user->canDo('VIEW_ADMIN');


    });

}
```

}

В модели User реализован метод canDo(), который осуществляет проверку наличия свойства VIEW_ADMIN, для просмотра пользователем панели администратора.

```
public function canDo($permission, $require = FALSE) {

    if(is_array($permission)) {
        dd($permission);
    }
    else {
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            foreach($role->perms as $perm) {
                if(str_is($permission, $perm->name)) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

В IndexController метод denies выдает исключение 403 если метод canDo возвращает false, и соответственно разрешает просмотр админки при возвращении true

```
class IndexController extends AdminController
{
//
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    if(Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN')) {
        abort(403);
    }

    $this->template = env('THEME').'.admin.index';
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->title = 'Панель администратора';
        return $this->renderOutput();

    }
```

}

Так задумано и прекрасно отрабатывает у автора в  версии 5.2, 
но у меня в версии 5.7 выдает исключение 403 в независимости от метода canDo.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, буду признателен за конструктивное пояснение, и прошу не судить строго.

Comment: я Gates никогда не использовал, но судя по коду `Gate::define` принимает параметр $user. По идее вам надо указать пользователя вот так: `if(Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN'), auth()->user()) {`. Заметил еще у вас в коде используется `env('THEME')`, это очень плохая практика, env должен вызываться только в конфиге и получать надо с конфига.

Comment: Такой синтаксис выдает syntax error, unexpected ','

`if(Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN'), auth()->user()) {
            abort(403);
        }`

Или я вас неправильно понял? 
Про env('THEME') - спасибо за совет, приму к сведению!

Comment: я извиняюсь, сюда не удобно код писать, опечатался, вот так попробуйте: `if(Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN', auth()->user())) { abort(403); }`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько к сожалению, не сработало
так же выдает исключение